# Openlayers cluster with some markers in same location

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I need an example for this scenario that I have a cluster with 5 or 10 markers and all of them have same latitude and longitude and if I click on the cluster all those markers will be showing as a circle with spaces.

Is it possible? If so could you please provide some sample code.

Comment: did u get any solution without using external libraries

Comment: same, looking for the ability to "spiderfy" an open layer 6 cluster without the use of an external library

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ol-ext library](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext).
There is a `ol.interaction.SelectCluster`: cluster springs apart to reveal the features on select.
[image]
See example online: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html

Comment: Has any solution for this one in core openlayers instead of third party ol-ext?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: In my example the expanded features are not arranged in a circle though, they are simply shown at their normal "unclustered" place on the map. Might be possible to additionally arrange them in a circle.*

So, I got the expansion working with an additional layer that contains the features that are not clustered. This is what I did:

1. I added a click event on the clustered layer that fires when the user clicks on a cluster:

   ```
   const select = new olInteraction.Select({
        layers: [clusterLayer],
        style: null
    });

   map.addInteraction(select);

   const selectableFeatures = select.getFeatures();

   selectableFeatures.on('add', (feature) => {

     const features = feature.element.get('features') || [];

     //is it a cluster with > 1 items?
     if (features.length > 1) {
       features.forEach((feature) => feature.set('cluster', false));
     }

   });
   ```
2. Then I ensured the cluster does not show the features that have been clicked on by setting the geometryFunction on the cluster:

   ```
    const clusterSource = new olSource.Cluster({
      distance: 80,
      geometryFunction: (feature) => {
        if (feature.get('cluster') === false) return null;
        return feature.getGeometry();
      },
      source,
    });
   ```
3. Then I created an additional vector layer that shows only the features where the property `cluster === false`:

   ```
      const vectorLayer = new olLayer.Vector({
      id,
      selectable: true,
      title: 'Layer that is not Clustered',
      source,
      style: (feature, resolution) => {
        if (feature.get('cluster') === false) {

          //styling of the expanded features goes here
          return [
            new olStyle.Style({
            image: new olStyle.Circle({
            radius: 30,
            scale: getScale(resolution) * 1.5,
            fill: new olStyle.Fill({
                color: (hover || selected) ? '#1F54A0' : 'rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)',
                })
              })
            })
          ];
        }

        //hide the clustered features on this layer
        return new olStyle.Style({});
      },
      zIndex:2,
      maxResolution: 10,
    });
   ```